# How to check if Azure datafactory pipeline is running without run id in C#

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is there a way in C# to find if pipeline is running without run ID ?

I have tried looking up, but could on find methods which take RunID and give status of pipeline

Comment: Can you add code of what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through `C#`, it might not be possible as `Pipeline Runs - Get` has the `runId` as the required parameter detailed documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipelineruns/get).

You can always try using `PowerShell` to check the run status by using cmdlet `Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2PipelineRun` where you can pass information such as   `ResourceGroupName, DataFactoryName, LastUpdatedAfter, LastUpdatedBefore, PipelineName`. More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datafactories/get-azurermdatafactoryv2pipelinerun?view=azurermps-5.4.0).